# Christoffel symbol for time component

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In Section 9.2, from "General Relativity: An Introduction for Physicists" by Hobson, I am trying to obtain the affine connections for the metric $$dS^2 = A(r)dt^2 - B(r)dr^2 - r^2(d\theta^2 + \sin^2\theta d\phi^2).$$

For this, I am setting my Lagrangian as $L = A\dot t^2 - B\dot r^2 - r^2(\dot \theta^2 + \sin^2 \theta \dot \phi^2)$ , where $\dot t = \dfrac{dt}{dS}$ and obtaining Geodesic equations by applying Euler-Lagrange equation to it.

However, I can't obtain component $\Gamma^{1}_{00} $ using this method, which would be equal to $\dfrac{dA}{dr}\dfrac{1}{2B}$

Step

[image]

Comment: You are simply missing the term when applying into the EL equations, that A is also a function of r.

Comment: Understood, Thanks a lot, I made a blunder not assuming A and B as a function of r itself evening though highlight it while posting this here. XD

Comment: A great help for you would be Susan Larsen's webpage [Lots of Calculations in General Relativity](https://physicssusan.mono.net/9035/General%20Relativity%20-%20Relativity%20demystified). Your problem you will find in [Chapter 11](https://physicssusan.mono.net/upl/9320/LotsChapter11TheSchwarzschildSpacetime21.3.2023.pdf) on pages 2, 3 and 4..

Comment: @JanG Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-hand side of the Euler-Lagrange equation

$$\frac{d}{ds} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial r}$$

is

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial r} = A'(r) \dot{t}^2 - B'(r) \dot{r}^2 - 2r \big( \dot{\theta}^2 + \sin^2 \theta \dot{\phi}^2 \big)$$

while the left-hand side is

$$\frac{d}{ds} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{r}} = \frac{d}{ds} \Big( -2 B(r) \dot{r} \Big) = -2B'(r) \dot{r}^2 - 2B(r) \ddot{r}$$

so that the Euler-Lagrange equation reads

$$ -2B(r) \ddot{r} - 2B'(r) \dot{r}^2 = A'(r) \dot{t}^2 - B'(r) \dot{r}^2 - 2r\big( \dot{\theta}^2 + \sin^2 \theta \dot{\phi}^2 \big)$$

or equivalently (for $B(r) \neq 0$)

$$ \ddot{r} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{B'(r)}{B(r)} \dot{r}^2 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{A'(r)}{B(r)} \dot{t}^2 - \frac{r}{B(r)} \big( \dot{\theta}^2 + \sin^2 \theta \dot{\phi}^2 \big) = 0$$

You can read off the Christoffels now, the Christoffel in question is

$$\Gamma^1_{00} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{A'(r)}{B(r)}$$

Comment: Thanks for showing the steps :)